# Add new non existing column in every document of collection

Tags: mongodb-query

I am adding the new column in an existing document 
My Existing Document format is:

```
{
      "_id": "5a6026e29cbcdc48083dae1a",
      "data": {
        "formList": [
          {
            "IdentificationDetails": [
              {
                "Status": "Data Entry Completed",
                "Form_Id": 1,
                "Interviewer_Name": "NAGARAJ.P",
                "Group_Id": 9,
                "Study_Id": "1",
                "Study_Name": "INDIAB",
                "Created_Emp_Id": "1",
                "Form_Name": "Food Frequency Questionnarie",
                "Visit_No": "1",
                "Volunteer_Id": "R270116",
                "Interview_Date": "2009-10-10T00:00:00Z",
                "Volunteer_Name": "RAJENDRA PAWAR"
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "VFoodDetails": [
              {
                "Portion_Size": 15,
                "Serving_Size": "0",
                "Food_Id": 737,
                "Value": "0",
                "Portion_Tool": 18,
                "Volunteer_Id": "R270116",
                "Meal_Session": 121,
                "Frequency_Serving": "Never"
              },
              {
                "Portion_Size": 168,
                "Serving_Size": "0",
                "Food_Id": 740,
                "Value": "0",
                "Portion_Tool": 177,
                "Volunteer_Id": "R270116",
                "Meal_Session": 121,
                "Frequency_Serving": "Never"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
```

I need to add the new column Group_Description in the object of an 'IdentificationDetails' Array.

My Required Json Document is :

```
{
      "_id": "5a6026e29cbcdc48083dae1a",
      "data": {
        "formList": [
          {
            "IdentificationDetails": [
              {
                "Status": "Data Entry Completed",
                "Form_Id": 1,
                "Interviewer_Name": "NAGARAJ.P",
                "Group_Id": 9,
                "Study_Id": "1",
                "Study_Name": "INDIAB",
                "Created_Emp_Id": "1",
                "Form_Name": "Food Frequency Questionnarie",
                "Visit_No": "1",
                "Volunteer_Id": "R270116",
                "Interview_Date": "2009-10-10T00:00:00Z",
                "Volunteer_Name": "RAJENDRA PAWAR",
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "VFoodDetails": [
              {
                "Portion_Size": 15,
                "Serving_Size": "0",
                "Food_Id": 737,
                "Value": "0",
                "Portion_Tool": 18,
                "Volunteer_Id": "R270116",
                "Meal_Session": 121,
                "Frequency_Serving": "Never"
              },
              {
                "Portion_Size": 168,
                "Serving_Size": "0",
                "Food_Id": 740,
                "Value": "0",
                "Portion_Tool": 177,
                "Volunteer_Id": "R270116",
                "Meal_Session": 121,
                "Frequency_Serving": "Never",
                 "Group_Description": "Urban"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
```

My Update Command which is created the column in the last of the json:

> db.FrequencyQuestionForm.update({"data.formList.IdentificationDetails.Group_Id"
>         :9.0 },{$set : {"Group_Description":"Urban"}},{ multi: true })

```
{
      "_id": "5a6026e29cbcdc48083dae1a",
      "data": {
        "formList": [
          {
            "IdentificationDetails": [
              {
                "Status": "Data Entry Completed",
                "Form_Id": 1,
                "Interviewer_Name": "NAGARAJ.P",
                "Group_Id": 9,
                "Study_Id": "1",
                "Study_Name": "INDIAB",
                "Created_Emp_Id": "1",
                "Form_Name": "Food Frequency Questionnarie",
                "Visit_No": "1",
                "Volunteer_Id": "R270116",
                "Interview_Date": "2009-10-10T00:00:00Z",
                "Volunteer_Name": "RAJENDRA PAWAR",
                "Group_Description": "Urban"
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "VFoodDetails": [
              {
                "Portion_Size": 15,
                "Serving_Size": "0",
                "Food_Id": 737,
                "Value": "0",
                "Portion_Tool": 18,
                "Volunteer_Id": "R270116",
                "Meal_Session": 121,
                "Frequency_Serving": "Never"
              },
              {
                "Portion_Size": 168,
                "Serving_Size": "0",
                "Food_Id": 740,
                "Value": "0",
                "Portion_Tool": 177,
                "Volunteer_Id": "R270116",
                "Meal_Session": 121,
                "Frequency_Serving": "Never"
              }
             ]
          }
        ]
      }, 
      "Group_Description": "Urban"
    }
```

Comment: your schema has two level of array nesting so it's kind of impossible doing it via mongodb. You have to fetch that particular documents and do it in the code then update entire document again.

Answer (score 1):

The command to add the new non-existing column in all mongodb documents in a collection is:

```
db.FrequencyQuestionForm.update(
    {'data.formList.IdentificationDetails.Group_Id': 9 },
    {'$set': {'data.formList.0.IdentificationDetails.0.Group_Description': "abc"}},{ multi: true } );
```